# Getting all files that have been submitted with a form using OneUp's UploaderBundle and blueimp's jQuery-file-upload

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, jquery-file-upload, oneupuploaderbundle

In out website, we wish to present the users with a form that would allow them to upload picture galleries. The form consists of a `<textarea>` for a description, a `<select>` with sharing options and the multiple file upload field.

We're using jQuery-file-upload's jquery-ui version, as seen in here: [link](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html) and our javascript code is pretty much identical. The only significant difference is that we also added a simple submit button, that sends out a POST request to the form's action.

The problem is that we need to reference ALL the files in a `GalleryPost` object, and the POST request that we get from the form only contains the values of `<textarea>` and `<select>`. Which makes sense, since the uploading is done asynchronously via separate requests.

Since we're using OneUpUploaderBundle to handle the actual uploads, we've tried enabling the orphanage feature [described here](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/orphanage.md), which *kinda* helps doing what we want, but as stated in the "known limitations" section, if the user does not submit the form, but starts over with a new one, the previously uploaded files will be submitted, together with the new ones, unless the session id is changed.

Simply put, we need a way to attach a list of files (names would suffice), that have been successfully uploaded, to the form's POST request, so that we could reference them in our `GalleryPost` object. Or maybe there is some other way to achieve the functionality we need?